# Unidirectional @OneToMany association fails equality test in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, wildfly

I have set up a unidirectional OneToMany relationship like the example in section 2.10.5.1 of  the JPA 2.1 spec:

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {

...

    @OneToMany
    private List<ServiceOrder> activeServiceOrders;

    public void setActiveServiceOrders( List<ServiceOrder> activeServiceOrders ) {

        this.activeServiceOrders = activeServiceOrders;
    }

    public List<ServiceOrder> getActiveServiceOrders() {

        return activeServiceOrders;
    }
}
```

The ServiceOrder class implements hashCode and equals using its auto-generated long id. They were implemented by Eclipse.

```
public class ServiceOrder implements Serializable {

    @TableGenerator( name = "generator_serviceOrder", table = "SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "LAST_VALUE_GEN", pkColumnValue = "SERVICE_ORDER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 0 )
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "generator_serviceOrder" )
    private long id;
...
    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object obj ) {

        if ( this == obj )
            return true;
        if ( obj == null )
            return false;
        if ( getClass() != obj.getClass() )
            return false;
        ServiceOrder other = (ServiceOrder ) obj;
        if ( id != other.id )
            return false;
        return true;
    }
...
}
```

Tables are all auto-generated as expected. Then, when I want to establish the relationship I do:

```
...
Client client = entityManager.find(...);
ServiceOrder so = entityManager.find(...);
client.getActiveServiceOrders().add( so );
...
```

Everything is fine until now, transaction commits successfully. Problem starts when I try to remove the relationship (in another transaction, another moment):

```
...
Client sameClient = entityManager.find(...);
ServiceOrder sameSo = entityManager.find(...);
log.info(sameClient.getActiveServiceOrders().size()); // "1", OK
log.info(sameClient.getActiveServiceOrders().contains(so)); // "false". Why?
sameClient.getActiveServiceOrders().remove(so); // does nothing, returns false
...
```

I debugged and discovered that the following is failing in ServiceOrder.equals():

```
...
if ( getClass() != obj.getClass() ) // different probably because JPA (Hibernate) proxies one of the objects
    return false; // returns
...
```

I found two temporary solutions:

1. Remove ServiceOrder equals() and hashCode();
   or
2. Make the relationship bidirectional (and of course update both sides every add/remove);

I don't understand this behavior. Why the difference in treatment if the relationship is uni or bi-directional? Also, if I get these entities in the context of the same transaction, how would fail the first equals test:

```
if ( this == obj )
    return true;
```

I'm using JPA 2.1 (Wildfly 8.1.0).

Best Regards and thank you in advance.
Renan

Comment: Here is the explanation why `getClass() != obj.getClass()` does not work: [Hibernate equals and proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013138/hibernate-equals-and-proxy)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the solution. But I would like to better undertand why this happens on unidirectional relationship, but does not happen if I make it bidirectional. Would this be Hibernate specific or would be the same on all JPA implementations? And how `if ( this == obj ) return true;` would fail if the two references are bound to the same EntityManager (same transaction)?

Answer (score 3):

You should override equals and hashCode but you should never use the ID for hash code unless you make the hashCode immutable and use the ID only [when it's not null for equality](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/).

Otherwise, prior to saving an Entity with the ID being null which is to be assigned during the flush time when you add a Transient entity to a collection, the moment it gets persisted and the ID is generated the equals/hashCode contract is going to broken.

Hibernate best practices suggest [using a business key](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/) for object equality/hashCode.

So quoting the reference documentation:

> The general contract is: if you want to store an object in a List, Map
> or a Set then it is a requirement that equals and hashCode are
> implemented so they obey the standard contract as specified in the
> documentation.
>
> To avoid this problem we recommend using the "semi"-unique attributes
> of your persistent class to implement equals() (and hashCode()).
> Basically you should think of your database identifier as not having
> business meaning at all (remember, surrogate identifier attributes and
> automatically generated values are recommended anyway). The database
> identifier property should only be an object identifier, and basically
> should be used by Hibernate only. Of course, you may also use the
> database identifier as a convenient read-only handle, e.g. to build
> links in web applications.
>
> Instead of using the database identifier for the equality
> comparison, you should use a set of properties for equals() that
> identify your individual objects. For example, if you have an "Item"
> class and it has a "name" String and "created" Date, I can use both to
> implement a good equals() method. No need to use the persistent
> identifier, the so-called "business key" is much better. It's a
> natural key, but this time there is nothing wrong with using it!

Comment: I wouldn't be so dogmatic with "should never use the ID for equality/hashing" statement.  I'm working on a big project that successfully uses ID as a hash key for several years. ID "fits this criteria nicely" (PRO JPA 2.0 book). The key point is to not compare entities that was not persisted yet. Maintaining hash key based on business attributes of the entity might be a great idea but is much more challenging.

Comment: After the entity is persisted, the surrogate key might work but it still opens the door for subtle issues, some inexperienced developers might introduce. The business key is much more resilient so I think it's worth the trouble to come up with a valid unique key combination. And almost always, each table row represents something different from all the other rows.

Comment: Why don't you give an example of the subtle issue inexperience developer can introduce? I challenge you also to give a methodology to introduce business key to entities. For simple examples like Currency its obvious but for more complicated like Address? Do you build hash from all fields of Address? If so, than what if an inexperience developer comes to the project and add a new column to the address without updating hashCode&equals?

Comment: A use case where you add new child entities to OneToMany Set, you pass the parent to merge and return it to the view, only to discover the Set doesn't iterate at all, even if the size is greater than zero. I fixed that once upon a time. The Address entity is a fairly simple example. Each address is unique, otherwise the postman would get lost while delivering the mail. Most of the time is: PostCode + Street Number + Apartment Number.

Comment: My project uses ID for equality and hashing all over place without problems, until this uni-directional relationship appeared. I understand that equality/hashing is a great debate in which a better case often depends on other details, but specially for this case, what is Hibernate doing differently on uni and bi-directional? Is there a guideline to make my code more JPA portable across implementations (Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc) ?

Comment: To make it JPA portable you need to stick with the JPA interfaces and annotations. But the equal/hashing are implementation details and you need to follow your JPA provider guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Don't override the `equals` and `hashCode`. Hibernate has its own implementation to find out the objects, and that's why you don't get the expected result.
This article explains more:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode?_sscc=t

Comment: What do you mean not to override equals and hashCode? Where did you get that from the official documentation. It's exactly the opposite. You should override equals and hashCode because otherwise the default reference equality is being employed. There's no such thing as "Hibernate's own implementation" for equals/hashCode. It's just standard Java equality contract that's being used. The only thing I agree with is that equality and hashCode play an important role, especially when using Hash collections.

Comment: @VladMihalcea hey man come down take a breath. It is not a good practice to implement equals and hashCode on entities. Why do you need them when the implementationis robust enough? Why should you take the riskand implement it? You should have a strong justification for that. How do you know your hashCode will generate  unique values?

Comment: Also if you have a look at documentation, it is explained how hibernate is working with hashCode and equals.

Comment: A business key is usually a column (or a combination of columns) that are enforced to be unique by the DB, so your equals is consistent across all Hibernate entity states. Quoting the reference documentation: "The general contract is: if you want to store an object in a List, Map or a Set then it is an requirement that equals and hashCode are implemented so they obey the standard contract as specified in the  documentation. nstead of using the database identifier for the equality comparison, you should use a set of properties for equals() that identify your individual objects."

Comment: equals() and hashCode() on Hibernate is a great debate. But how about JPA? I would like my code to be as portable as possible among other JPA implementations (EclipseLink, TopLink, etc). I don't know much of implementations specifics, I try to adhere to the JPA spec as much as I can. What you guys would recommend to best fit this portability requirement?

Comment: @VladMihalcea dude If you use composite keys then you should override `equals` and `hashCode`, otherwise there is no point. JPA (or if using pure implementation like `Hibernate`) will do the `hashCode` on `ID` for you. That's why I said, don't override `equals` and `hashCode`. Look at his example, he has just one primary key, so he doesn't need to override `hashCode` and `equals`

Comment: @Renan Specifics are the same, no matter you use `JPA` or `Hibernate`. `Hibenate` must follow the specifications. You can override `hashCode` and `equals` on JPA (with any underlying ORM). But if you don't have a composite key or embedded entity, try to avoid overriding `hashCode` and `equals`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Still curious as why the behavior is different on bi-directional relationships and why, if in the same transaction and retrieved from the same EntityManager, the first test of the equals (`if ( this == obj ) return true;`) would fail.